# delete random data in mysql

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I want to delete some random data from my table, and cut 90% rows (I have very large data, I just need a sample), table looks like this:

```
ID    |Trans_No    |Doctor_ID |Trans_Type                    |PM |Cost
12340 |10.853329   |          |ADMINISTRASI                  |   |0.00
12341 |10.853329   |1004      |JASA MEDIS                    |   |25000.00
12342 |10.853329   |          |OBAT RESEP FARMASI NO : 177   |F  |2000.00
12343 |10.836033   |          |ADMINISTRASI                  |   |0.00
12344 |10.836033   |1001      |JASA MEDIS                    |   |25000.00
12345 |10.836033   |          |OBAT RESEP FARMASI NO : 317   |F  |0.00
12346 |10.836032   |          |ADMINISTRASI                  |   |0.00
12347 |10.836032   |1004      |JASA MEDIS                    |   |25000.00
12348 |10.836032   |          |PEMERIKSAAN RADIOLOGI NO 092.1|R  |15000.00
12349 |10.836034   |1064      |JASA MEDIS                    |   |25000.00
12350 |10.836034   |          |PEMERIKSAAN RADIOLOGI NO 093.1|R  |20000.00
```

I think this query will work:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE RAND() <= 0.9
```

but as you can see, some data has same trans_no, if one trans_no is deleted, the other data that has same trans_no should be deleted to, is there any query to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should select eligible `trans_no` first and then delete them, like this:

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE trans_no IN (
    SELECT trans_no
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT trans_no FROM my_table) x
    WHERE rand() <= 0.9
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to have an inner query for this.

First you have to find the `trans_no` to be deleted

```
    SELECT 
            trans_no
    FROM 
           (SELECT DISTINCT trans_no FROM my_table)
    WHERE rand()
```

Then You have to have separate delete query like this

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE trans_no IN (Put the above query here)
```

Finally

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE  trans_no IN (
        SELECT 
                trans_no
        FROM 
               (SELECT DISTINCT trans_no FROM my_table) as derived_table
        WHERE rand()
)
```

Comment: your query has little error here, derived table must have its own alias, but thanks for your explanation, i get it now